# How can I not have high memory usage and not recalculate output arrays multiple times for dask gufunc functions?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, memory, dask

I've written a custom function that does a reduction on 3 arrays simultaneously that are too large to be kept in memory. I am using `dask.array.apply_gufunc` to apply my function blockwise on my set of arrays based on reading docs/issues for dask. Below is my test code:

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

def stack(data, uncertainties, mask, nsigma=5):
    # Estimate the scatter in the data to reject outliers
    # The magic numbers here are the +- sigma cumulative percentiles
    lower_sigma, med, upper_sigma = np.percentile(data, [15.86552, 50.0, 84.13447], axis=-1)
    sigma = (upper_sigma - lower_sigma) / 2.0
    pixels_to_reject = np.logical_or(np.abs(data - np.expand_dims(med, -1)) > (nsigma * np.expand_dims(sigma, -1)), mask > 0)
    # Do we want to not throw away pixels if all the mask values are bad?
    n_good_pixels = mask.shape[-1] - pixels_to_reject.sum(axis=-1)
    all_bad_pixels = n_good_pixels == 0
    pixels_to_reject[all_bad_pixels, :] = False
    
    n_good_pixels[all_bad_pixels] = mask.shape[-1]

    data[pixels_to_reject] = 0.0
    uncertainties[pixels_to_reject] = 0.0
    stacked_data = data.sum(axis=-1) / n_good_pixels
    
    stacked_uncertainty = np.sqrt(uncertainties.sum(axis=-1) / (n_good_pixels ** 2.0))
    stacked_mask = np.zeros_like(stacked_data, dtype=np.uint8)
    stacked_mask[all_bad_pixels] = np.bitwise_or.reduce(mask, axis=-1)[all_bad_pixels]
    return stacked_data, stacked_uncertainty, stacked_mask

da.random.seed = 1909810234
da_data = da.random.normal(10, 0.1, size=(4097, 4096, 200), chunks=(100, 100, 200))
da_mask = da.zeros((4097, 4096, 200), chunks=(100, 100, 200), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, j in zip(np.random.randint(0, 4095, size=100), np.random.randint(0, 4096, size=100)):
    da_mask[j, i, :] = 1
da_uncertainties = da.ones_like(da_data, chunks=(100, 100, 200)) * 0.1

da_stacked_data, da_stacked_uncertainty, da_stacked_mask = da.apply_gufunc(stack, "(i),(i),(i)->(),(),()", 
                                                                           da_data, da_uncertainties, da_mask)
output_data, output_uncertainty, output_mask = da_stacked_data.compute(), da_stacked_uncertainty.compute(), da_stacked_mask.compute()
```

This code does run, but with some unexpected performance issues. The first issue is that this takes an enormous amount of memory (50 GB see image). The chuck sizes should be small so I suspect that the arrays are getting rechunked under the hood somewhere. How can I run this without taking more memory than a few times the chunk size? Watching the activity monitor also showed that it appears to be doing the same calculation 3 times (each time we call compute). How do I get the code to return all 3 reduced arrays in one pass on the data?

Thank you for your help!
[The image here shows the memory usage with 50GB and the multiple runs to compute each array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZDql.png)

Comment: Your input `da_data` is 4K*4K*200 which is 3.4Gb, which is a bit large for a testcase; how much physical memory does your machine have? When you scale the datasize down, how large datasize can you handle before the rechunking behavior happens?

Comment: There are more accurate memory profiling tools for dask than MacOS Activity Manager. First there's base pandas `df. memory_usage()`. Can you report the base memory usage before you start the job? Why don't you delete and garbage-collect your temporaries from before the stacking line? Then when running dask, there's [Measuring Dask memory usage with dask-memusage](https://blog.dask.org/2021/03/11/dask_memory_usage)

Comment: @smci Thanks for getting back to me. My machine has 16 GB of physical memory. You are of course correct about the size of the dataset. However, the chunk size is 100x100x200 which is only 16 MB. Given my memory size I shouldn't be seeing any real memory pressure even with 100 chunks in memory. Cutting all dimensions down by a factor of 2 (factor of 8 total) still shows memory usage of 6GB (more than 10 times the 425MB of the smaller dataset). This is fundamentally different than if I run %time out = da_data.mean(axis=-1).compute() (on the large dataset) which uses no noticeable extra memory.

Comment: @smci In terms of memory profilers I agree there are better tools. I hadn't felt it necessary to use a less blunt instrument though given the egregious amount of memory things were taking. I'm not using pandas here. Is there a similar tool that that works with dask arrays? I'm reading up on the dask-memusage task.